# Search Value and highlight Row

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am using conditional formatting to search a value in a cell and apply it to a specific column. If the data matches it highlights the entire row. The issue I am having is that if I search the value of "20" and that number is a part of a value in the search range such as "120" it highlights the "120" row also. Is there a way to only highlight the rows that contain values of "20" and not highlight partial matches?

Here is the formula I am using.

```
=SEARCH($C$6,$C10)
```

Best,

D

Comment: ```=$C$6=$C10```, I guess

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this and it does not work. With that formula the conditional formatting stops working all together. Thank you for your input though:)

Comment: are you able to provide a link to an example google sheet, so we can see what you data looks like

Comment: Could you put together a quick example so we can jump in and try to help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here's how it's done:

```
=$A1=20
```

[image]

```
=$A1=$D$1
```

[image]

if that won't work you have a formatting issue. in that case use:

```
=$A1*1=$D$1*1
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. I got this to work on manually inputted information, but it will not work if the data is being populated by a Query.

Comment: @DavidCruz can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help. There was a formatting issue in the main sheet, so I re-made the sheet and used this formula in the conditional formatting.

```
=SEARCH($B$6,$C10)
```

Now everything seems to work as intended.

Thank you again,

D